# How to parse an .msg file in php?

Tags: php, msg, eml, email-parsing

Is there any way for parsing the Outlook .msg files in PHP? My requirement is to parse an .msg file and convert each conversation(message) in it to separate files(Preferably .eml files).

Comment: According to http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/163537-parse-an-outlook-email/ the .msg file is binary. Good luck.

Comment: Finally used the perl script at http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv and it worked perfect by converting all the messages in a conversation in an msg file to plain text

Answer (score 3):

Well, .msg files are ["COM stuctured storage OLE2 compound documents"](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/), which probably means that it will be difficult to open it in PHP.

PHP does have a Windows [COM extension](https://www.php.net/COM), but I do not know if it can be used.

Comment: This is likely the best option if available.